# How to reload a the entire tree using fancytree widget (Yii2) after dropping a node

Tags: javascript, yii2, fancytree

I want my tree to reload after I drop a node. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to call the function on the tree.

I've tried using tree, the id of the container, fancytree, you name it.. 
Here's the source where I load the fancytree widget:

```
echo FancytreeWidget::widget([
'options' =>[
    'source' => $chapters,
    'extensions' => ['dnd'],
    'icons' => false,
    'activeVisible' => true,
    'dnd' => [
        'preventVoidMoves' => true,
        'preventRecursiveMoves' => true,
        'autoExpandMS' => 400,
        'dragStart' => new JsExpression('function(node, data) {
            startNode = node;
            return true;
        }'),
        'dragEnter' => new JsExpression('function(node, data) {
            return true;
        }'),
        'dragDrop' => new JsExpression('function(node, data) {
            dropNode = node;
            data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
            updatePosition();
            node.render(force=true);
        }'),
    ],
],
```

]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around some more I came to the following solution:

I was looking into the data parameter that is given to the function after dropping the node. There I found tree on which I can call reload().

```
'dragDrop' => new JsExpression('function(node, data) {
            data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
            dropNode = node;
            updatePosition();
            data.tree.reload();
        }'),
```